# Web Accessibility in Phaser HTML 5 Game Framework

Tags: html, accessibility, phaser-framework

Recently I have come across a major issue with Phaser game framework which is regarding Web Accessibility. Screen readers are not able to read the instructions showing in the Instructions Pop-up in games while playing game.

Scenario: Before playing game user should click ok and accept to agree the rules before game start which is nightmare for screen readers not able to pick up the text and instruct the user to take action. Due to this users are being stuck up to play the game which is made so simple interactions

Answer (score -1):

Text written inside the canvas directly with `.add.text(...)` creates a [Phaser.GameObjects.Text](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html) that is not readable by a screen reader (is not even selectable!)

You could use [Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement.html) instead.
I've checked one of my projects and text written inside DOMElement can be properly read by screen reader (test done with Screen Reader browser extension by chrome.google.com)

**EDIT:**
I found this interesting conversation (from 2017) [HTML5 Canvas is the least accessible thing to be put on the Web since Flash](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14161598) that is worth reading.
As a solution (or hack for someone) they propose use of DOM element that can be read by screen reader, or the usage of alt text for the canvas.

Further research bring me to this blog post [HTML  Accessibility](https://pauljadam.com/demos/canvas.html) that describes how to use `aria-label` and `role` attributes to let screen readers read canvas' context.